In natural language processing, what is the name for the technique in which a sentence is modeled as a tree in order to generate simpler sentences?
In natural language processing, there are times when we model a complex and/or compound sentence as a tree (or hierarchy) of simpler sentences.
The tree-model (hierarchical model) can help us translate a long sentence σ₀ into two or more sentences in set XS such that for any x ∈ XS, sentence x is shorter than sentence σ₀ (sigma-knot) and the concatenation of all sentences x ∈ XS is longer than sentence σ₀.
What is the name for the process of creating this type of prefix tree?

Step One (input)

Entiendo que estás intentando practicar y mejorar tu español conmigo, y agradezco tu esfuerzo.


Step Two
Entiendo que estás/
├─ intentando practicar tu español conmigo/
├─ mejorar tu español conmigo/
├─ agradezco tu esfuerzo/


Step Three (output)


Entiendo que estás intentando practicar tu español conmigo

Entiendo que estás mejorar tu español conmigo.

Entiendo que estás agradezco tu esfuerzo




I guess you mean sentence segmentation using tree structures. Because this process involves breaking down a complex sentence into shorter, simpler sentences. Also, it describes the task of dividing text into meaningful units.
Please follow this blog for more clarity: https://mohamedbakrey094.medium.com/a-simple-explanation-for-sentence-segmentation-and-implementation-72c66476e72f
